How to restore the code from a previous deployment
Short question: How do I restore/retrieve the code (html,gs) for a previous deployment?
Longer: I have some coding experience from many years ago, but am for all practical purposes a novice. I have used ChatGPT 4o to help with creating a Google Apps script to interface with a Google Sheet. After spending several days on it, I had a good and comprehensive interface that worked well. Normally, I save backup files of everything I do, but I couldn't find a download option in Google Apps Script. At some point, the code went haywire. (I think ChatGPT started hallucinating and lost track, maybe due to general user overload.) At this point, I have an old deployment that works well, but not the code for it. I know the code must be somewhere since it's used for the deployment, but I don't know how to access it. If there is a way, please explain it in simple terms :) I would be very grateful since recreating it all from scratch would take another several days of work.
What I expected: I expected a simple way to retrieve the code from an old deployment.

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site encourages askers to self-answer their questions but the answers should be posted as an answer, not as a question "update". Refs. [answer],  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

To restore Google Apps Script project version you might use the Google Apps Script REST API directly or through tools like CLASP (command-line program) and Google Apps Script GitHub Assistant (Google Chrome extension).

When a new deployment is created and updated, Google Apps Script automatically saves a new version. Versions can be used for several things but don't include a built-in way to restore an old version as a HEAD deployment.
From Versions.

View a previous version
To view a previously created version within your script project, take the following steps:

In your script project, click Project History.
Under Project history, select the version you want to view. To view the description of a version, hold the pointer over the version number.


Related

How to restore an old version in Google Apps Script's new editor? (Web Applications Stack Exchange).

